# datepicker javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, datepicker

i am having little problem with my javascript:

### js:

```
<!-- Call datepicker through image button -->
<script>
function OpenDatePicker(DatePicker)
{
    if (document.createEvent) 
    {
            var id = '.' + DatePicker;
            $(id).focus();
    }
}
</script>
```

### html:

```
<div class="row-form">
    <div class="span2" style="margin-top: 06px">Date1:</div>
    <div class="span4" style="height: 29px;">
        <input type="text" class="datepicker" style="margin-left: 40px;" />
    </div>
    <img style="margin-left: 12px; cursor: pointer" src="../../img/Date.png" onClick="OpenDatePicker(this);" />
</div>
<div class="row-form" style="margin-top: -19px;">
    <div class="span2" style="margin-top: 06px">Date2:</div>
    <div class="span4" style="height: 29px;">
        <input type="text" class="datepicker" style="margin-left: 40px;" />
    </div>
    <img style="margin-left: 12px; cursor: pointer" src="../../img/Date.png" onClick="OpenDatePicker(this);" />
</div>
```

the problem is that i am using date pick many times in my form. so when i click on whichever input field and select the date, it only changes date in one particular field (i.e if i click on 'Date1' input field for example the date changes in 'Date2' input field and not in its input field). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Before focusing* the datepicker, you should have *initialized* the `datepicker` to the textbox like

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Then it works perfectly.

### [JSFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/GzZ4h/1/)

---

```
  var id = '.' + DatePicker;
  $(id).focus();
```

Here you're using `class` name for `focus()` event, which always refers to the *last* textbox.  Instead assign `id`s and tune your code as below in fiddle.

### [JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/GzZ4h/2/)

Check the difference between these fiddles so that you can understand.